# compile contract success but some function don't work once it's deployed

Tags: solidity, remix

I tried to modify someone works that I found in stackexchange for learning reference. I was going to make shoppinglist contract, it could be compiled but when I deployed the contract, getitemcount, shopping loop, and shoppinglists functions couldn't work. The problem is when I add a new shopping item, it's recorded in shopping items but not for shopping list.

here is my script.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract MyContract{
struct item{
    string itemname;
    uint itemprice;
}

mapping(address => item) public shoppingitems;
address[] public shoppinglist;

event shoppinglog(address item, string name, uint price);

function addshoppingitem(address itemID, string memory itemname, uint itemprice) external{
    shoppingitems[itemID] = item(itemname, itemprice);
    
}

function getitemcount() public view returns(uint count){
    return shoppinglist.length;
}

function shoppingloop() public {
    for(uint i=0; i<studentList.length; i++){
        emit shoppinglog(shoppinglist[i], shoppingitems[shoppinglist[i]].itemname, shoppingitems[shoppinglist[i]].itemprice);
    }
}
}
```

I guess, the problem is come from shoppinglist variable that isn't defined properly, but I can't debug it. can somebody help me?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You contract actually cannot be compiled. You need to replace `studentList` by `shoppinglist` in the `shoppingloop` function.

The `getitemcount` method always returns 0 because no item address is saved in the `shoppinglist` array.
Just add `shoppinglist.push(itemID);` in the `addshoppingitem` method to fix this. You should also check the `itemId` address not to overwrite previously saved items.

A quick remark about the `shoppingloop` function : this is not a good practice to iterate over unbounded array as the gas cost needed to execute this function could become very high. Indeed one could call multiple times `addshoppingitem` to intentionally increase the `shoppinglist` size, making `shoppingloop` too expensive.